# making a function return multiple objects

Tags: python, cpython

in python, a function returns only one object, that is something like,

```
def f():
    return 1, 'a', True
```

```
type(f())
```

```
tuple
```

but I would like to change this behavior and make a function return multiple objects.
so instead of a return type, there would be multiple return types, something like,

```
int, str, bool
```

where is the implementation in cpython which describes that a function could return only one object, and how difficult is it to change,
i would like to do this to understand the way things work in cpython, as i have recently downloaded it on my local computer.

one application of this is,

```
op.eq(unpack(['a', 'A']))
```

where, `unpack` would be our hypothetical function which returns two objects.

```
str, str
```

and can be used with `op.eq`

Comment: How do you imagine this would function any differently than the existing usage of returning a tuple of objects?

Comment: You could just return everything you want as a JSON and then loop through or pick and choose what you want to do from there.

Comment: i would like to create a function `unpack` which returns multiple objects, which would be the substitute for `*`. in the current state, as a function returns only one object, so, I cannot unpack a tuple into multiple objects, so, the function `unpack` is not possible.

Comment: What is wrong with `def f():  return 'a', 'b', 'c'` followed by `a, b, c = f()`?

Comment: By the way, in C (the language that CPython is written in) you also cannot return multiple values directly. You can return a pointer to a data structure that has multiple values, which is really how we return multiple things.

Comment: What you want would require a change to the entire Python data model.

Answer (score 0):

In other languages like C++ or C#, this kind of requirement can be achieved by pass by reference.

Somewhat similar can be achieved using `SimpleNamespace` in python

> SimpleNamespace allows us to set arbitrary attributes.

Take a look at below example which is pretty much self explanatory

```
from types import SimpleNamespace

#INSTANCE OF SIMPLENAMESPACE
ns = SimpleNamespace()

#FUNCTION WHICH MODIFIES THE VARIABLES ACCEPTS SIMPLANAMESPACE OBJECT
def func(nsInstance):
    nsInstance.counter = nsInstance.counter + 1
    nsInstance.str = nsInstance.str + 'World'


#THE INTENDED VARIABLES, ADD TO SIMPLANAMESPACEINSTANCE
ns.counter = 0
ns.str = 'Hello'

#PASS THE OBJECT
func(ns)

#PRINT
print(ns.counter)
print(ns.str)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not possible without changing the language itself. You are going to have to resign yourself to

```
op.eq(*['a', 'A'])
```

The `*` is not really an operator; it's part of the *syntax* for function calls.